# Concatenation in JS functions

Tags: javascript, syntax, concatenation

First question here.  I am doing Codecademy's JS basics course and have run into a question concerning concatenation in functions.

I have:

```
var greeting = function(name){

console.log("Hello, "+"" +name);

};
```

Obviously, when I call this function with:

```
greeting("Chris");
```

I get, `Hello, Chris`

What if I wanted to spice that up a bit and have the output say, `Hello, Chris.  How are you doing today?`

I tried several different things that all lead to syntax errors.  For example:

```
var greeting = function(name){

console.log("Hello, "+"" +name "." ""+" How are you doing today?);

};
```

So, the question is how do I join the next strings after including the function output following the initial string?  I don't know if that sentence makes any sense.  So, In plain english, how do I get the period and the subsequent question in there after the output, `Hello, Chris`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `+` operator.

```
console.log("Hello, "+"" +name "." + ""+" How are you doing today?);
```

You also have a couple of empty strings that could be removed:

```
console.log("Hello, " + name "." + " How are you doing today?);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you may know that here is not the place to ask such questions but I have to tell you that, javascript concatenation uses the `join()` function which uses the comma `,` for joining if you dont provide it any arguments (as you provided `""`)
Use `" "` (quotes with space between) instead of `""`